# How to use ReactTestUtils to Simulate onChange event to update State

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to run unit tests on a simple score keeping component in React. My component has two State values, `score` and `newPoints`. An input element specifies the `newPoints` to add, and a button adds that to the `score`.

[image: Score keeping component]

Game.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Game() {
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);
  const [newPoints, setNewPoints] = useState(0);

  const AddPoints = (numPins) => {
    setScore(score + numPins);
  };

  const handlePointsChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.valueAsNumber); // value received is 3
    setNewPoints(event.target.valueAsNumber);
  };

  const handleAdd = () => {
    console.log(newPoints); // newPoints is still 0
    AddPoints(newPoints);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Game</h1>
      <p id="ScoreLabel">Score:{score}</p>
      <input
        id="PointsInput"
        type="number"
        onChange={handlePointsChange}
        value={newPoints}
      />
      <button id="AddButton" onClick={handleAdd}>
        Add
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Game;
```

**Problem:** The component works fine in my browser but I can't seem to get the unit tests working.

The `ReactTestUtils.Simulate` function in the test script successfully calls my component's `handlePointsChange` and the `valueAsNumber` received is correct. However, when my test script simulates a mouse click via `dispatchEvent`, the value of `newPoints` in `handleAdd` is still zero. It seems as though the value of `newPoints` state hasn't been updated yet, even after calling `setNewPoints`

Game.test.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ReactTestUtils from "react-dom/test-utils"; // ES6
import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils";
import Game from "./Game";

let container;
let scoreLabel;
let pointsInput;
let addButton;

beforeEach(() => {
  container = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(container);
  act(() => {
    ReactDOM.render(<Game />, container);
  });
  scoreLabel = container.querySelector("#ScoreLabel");
  pointsInput = container.querySelector("#PointsInput");
  addButton = container.querySelector("#AddButton");
});
afterEach(() => {
  document.body.removeChild(container);
  container = null;
  scoreLabel = null;
  addButton = null;
});

it("Add 3 points, Score should be 3", () => {
  act(() => {
    ReactTestUtils.Simulate.change(pointsInput, {
      target: { valueAsNumber: 3 },
    });
    addButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", { bubbles: true }));
  });
  expect(scoreLabel.textContent).toBe("Score:3");
});
```

Console log:

```
FAIL  src/Game.test.js
  ● Console

    console.log
      3

      at handlePointsChange (src/Game.js:12:13)

    console.log
      0

      at handleAdd (src/Game.js:17:13)

  ● Add 3 points, Score should be 3

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "Score:3"
    Received: "Score:0"
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction to get this unit test to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get the tests working by putting each event in separate `act()` blocks.

I guess this way it ensures that everything within the first `act()` block will finish rendering before executing the second `act()` block.

```
it("Add 3 points, Score should be 3", () => {
  act(() => {
    ReactTestUtils.Simulate.change(pointsInput, {
      target: { valueAsNumber: 3 },
    });
  });
  act(() => {
    addButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", { bubbles: true }));
  });
  expect(scoreLabel.textContent).toBe("Score:3");
});
```